# custom Page_List concrete5

Tags: php, block, concrete5

Hope someone can help me with this, i've had a search but can't find anything on it, however i'm sure i've seen it done before.

What i'm after is creating multiple page list views, for example. 
If i had a home page, that would show 
blocks/page_list/home_view.php

And then on an about page, it would call in

blocks/page_list/about_view.php

Is this possible? if so how do i go about doing it? I understand that i would call it via clicking on the block in the frontend and adding a page_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured it out.

Create a directory called templates within the blocks/page_list directory then put your homepage.php and about.php within that templates directory.

Then on the site click on the Page List block and go to Custom Templates and your two template options should show up there then select the correct one.